# How do you change your screen's color temperature?

Tags: color-management

How do I go about changing my laptop's display's color temperature? And I don't mean through something like the Red, Green, Blue sliders in the NVIDIA config menu. I'm talking about like adjusting in degrees, like editing a photo's white balance.

So now I've found Redshift and it's doing me pretty good. I thought it might be helpful if I out here the command I'm using.

```
redshift -t 5000:5000 -g .5
```

By adding this to my start up commands I should be good.

I'm still open to other suggestions, because I'd like something that actually edited my xorg.conf or something like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Redshift adjusts the color temperature of your screen according to your surroundings. This may help your eyes hurt less if you are working in front of the screen at night.

I'm not sure if this is what you need because, as far as I know, it won't let you adjust the colour temperature manually. It may help though, so [**Here's**](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) the website anyway.

Comment: Heh, I just started trying this. It's working pretty well... accept blacks just aren't as deep as they were on my old screen, but that just might be a fault of this new one.

Comment: my eyes thank you for this tip. (would be nice if OP could add the link to Redshift website in the question)

Answer (score 23):

`redshift -O 5000` works for instantly turning on warm mode instead of messing with location data

Comment: To turn off, use `redshift -x`

Comment: Normal 6500, by default night 3500, day 5700, min 1000, max 25000.

Comment: Oh man! This command is a life-saver!

Comment: But should you launch something like `nvidia-settings`, and this change gets reverted. Better use something like `redshift -l0:0 -t 5000:5000`, which also doesn't mess with location data, being explicitly set to Greenwich/equator.

Comment: It lasts for like 5 sec and then turns back to normal. and it prints "Using method `randr'."

Answer (score 5):

If you've got any form of colour-calibration hardware (or can find a profile on the internet) then `gnome-color-manager` will load and apply monitor calibration system-wide.

Windows drivers for monitors and laptops will often come with an .icm colour profile you can use, which, while not perfect, would almost certainly be better than nothing.

Comment: Then check this tools: `gcm-viewer`, `gcm-import`, `gcm-inspect`, `gcm-picker`, `gcm-calibrate`.

Answer (score 2):

### This follows @CornSmith answer :

1. Check **System Panel** icon for *RedShift App*

[image]

2. **Disable** it.
3. **Execute** following command

> `redshift -O 3000`

4. **Color temperature** of your display should change
5. To revert, just go to **System Panel** and **Enable it**, *Automatic Feature* will be back!

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using proprietary drivers, its quite easy with the built in gamma and color control, otherwise follow the methods listed above. Even Intel cards have GPU tools that can be installed via x-swat ppa.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `sct` (set color temperature?).  If you like small, compact programs with few dependencies, `sct` might be a good option.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=sct

Answer (score 0):

LPROF http://lprof.sourceforge.net/ seems to be your best bet for adjusting color temperature via software.  There's also ArgyllCMS which looks to have an even steeper learning curve.

I have not used either but LPROF is available as an ubuntu package.  sudo aptitude install lprof

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I tried LPROF. I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong, but the profile I made did nothing, even after trying to load it using xcalib...

Answer (score 0):

I installed the f.lux gui, but have scripted xflux a bit instead of using the gui, to just make the changes when I wanted. on 10.04, redshift was out of date.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you scripted `xflux`?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/873717/507051 about tweaking `xflux`.